# JSSOR bug - full width scaling on mobile Safari orientation change

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari, jssor

When changing orientation from landscape to portrait on an iPhone the slider ends up slightly zoomed in, it does not revert to its original portrait state/size.

see [this](https://www.jssor.com/demos/full-window-for-pc.slider). (on an iphone)

The [mobile demo](https://www.jssor.com/demos/full-window-for-mobile.slider) does not have this issue, but contains only portrait images. As soon as you use landscape pictures it will. I presume, because of the use of portrait-only pictures, that this is a known problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue is solved by adding user-scalable=no and viewport-fit=cover to the viewport.

we use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```